# ubuntu server 10.04 installation failed

Tags: 10.04

I have installed based software find in ubuntu 10.04 lts server but not able to install software and grub. I get an error " Installation setup failed" .repeatedly same error.

Pl. help

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu Server 10.04 (Lucid Lynx) reaches End of Life on April 30, 2015, a week after the date that your question was posted. Take this opportunity to download and install Ubuntu Server 14.04, which will be supported by security and maintenance updates until April, 2019.

Ubuntu Server 14.04 cannot be installed on a potato, but it does support a wide variety of hardware because of its low systems requirements.

#### Ubuntu Server 14.04 systems requirements

- Standard installation

  - Ubuntu 14.04 Server Edition supports 3 major architectures: Intel x86, AMD64 and ARM.
  - 1 GHz processor
  - 512 MB of system memory (RAM)
  - 1 GB of disk space (base system)
  - 1.75 GB of disk space (all tasks installed)
  - Graphics card and monitor capable of 640x480
- Minimal installation

  - Ubuntu 14.04 Server Edition supports 3 major architectures: Intel x86, AMD64 and ARM.
  - 300 MHz processor
  - 256 MB of system memory (RAM) 64-bit, 192 MB RAM 32-bit
  - 700 MB of disk space (base system)
  - 1.4 GB of disk space (all tasks installed)
  - Graphics card and monitor capable of 640x480